# how can i create my own column with my default set values in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
SELECT  
    (
    select "auto pricing" as bucket_names
    union all
    select "non-autopricing" as bucket_names
    union all
    select "activeprice" as bucket_names
    ) AS looker_test_1_bucket_names
FROM `wmt-dev.mydataset.looker_test_1`
     AS looker_test_1
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    1
LIMIT 500
```

---

I have written this query to create below "bucket_names" column with my own inserted dummy values but I am getting this below Error. how to resolve this?

this is what i want to achieve:

```
| bucket_names| 
| -------- | 
| auto pricing| 
| non-autopricing|
| activeprice|
```

---

this is what i got as error

> ERROR:Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Comment: You can use a with instead. You can also remove the from because your don't look inside the from table.